# Eclipse Updating the compiler compliance to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, rtc

I am having some trouble updating the compiler compliance of my eclipse workspace (I am actually using RTC, but it is essentially eclipse).
Currently, it uses a jdk of 1.6 so I can change the JDK compliance to a limit of 1.6.

However, I am using jdk 1.7 for my project -I have added it as a JRE -

```
preferences --> Java --> Installed JRE --> added jre with the jdk 1.7 directory.
```

However, even though I use this as the default JRE it does not allow me to change the compiler compliance level to 1.7.

I am guessing that there is something I am missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please mention exact version of eclipse

Answer (score 12):

The Compiler compliance level is **Version Dependent** in eclipse. If you are using Eclipse 3.7 or lower then you won't get 1.7 compliance. Use Eclipse JUNO or higher.

For more on [JDT Core 7](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7) and its release related information

**UPDATE:**

Even [eclipse 3.7.1](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-java7.htm) version supports Java 7 features and compliance level.

Comment: I am using RTC, so perhaps I will have to look at getting a newer version

Comment: Yes I use JUNO and it has compliance level of 1.7

Comment: Check the update. Even eclipse 3.7.1 version supports Java 7 compliance level.

Answer (score 6):

I use eclipse 3.6.1 with installed JRE 1.7 and I was able to set Java compliance level to 1.7 (on the workspace level - preferences).
In some workspaces I could do that right in the Preferences, in some workspaces I had to do that in a "hard way" updating several properties in the file:

    `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`


Here are changed lines:

    `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.7
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.7
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.7`

Maybe it was just enough to change the line with "org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance" property , but I did all three for the sake of completeness and consistency.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using eclipse 3.7 then you add 1.7 into compliance level by following way:-

- right click on project
- click on Build path->Configure Build Path->project Facets
- there you can see one link 'convert to faceted form'. click on it
- mark java and select verion 1.7 from dropdown which is present in front of java tab
- click on apply and click ok
- now you can see that 1.7 version is appeared in compliance level

Note:- Before above step you have to add JRE System library in Build path for jdk1.7

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project you have in use, click `Properties`, go to `Java Compiler`, and set `Compiler compilance level` to `1.8`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKAlh.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWMvZ.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

Select your project, then go to Project -> properties.
In Properties -> Java Compiler.
Under JDK Compliance if "use compliance from execution environment " is checked then uncheck it and you would see a dropdown in from of Compiler Compliance Level. Chose your desired version from here.

Click on Apply and Close.
Hopefully, this would resolve the issue.