# Adding facebook SDK 4.2.0 to eclipse

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I added facebook sdk as mentioned here, [Android Facebook SDK 4 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379890/android-facebook-sdk-4-in-eclipse).

I also have an updated sdk.

As mentioned in step 2:Fixing errors i did every thing as mentioned, it is showing `The import android.annotation cannot be resolved` even though i added `annotations.jar` in support folder.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Java 7 (1.7 here), you needed to do

```
HashMap<String, String> mHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And not:

```
HashMap<String, String> mHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Its referred to as the diamond operator, and is not backwards-compatible with earlier versions of Java.

Check your code.

Comment: then i would have to change it everywhere in facebook-sdk

Comment: why the solution provided didn't worked for me? what am i doing wrong

Comment: A possible solution: upgrade your Eclipse to allow 1.7. I think that is the problem then.

Comment: i am having eclipse juno and as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463067/eclipse-updating-the-compiler-compliance-to-1-7 it supports java 7

Comment: Did you have version 3.7.1  or higher?

Comment: yes it has Version: 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83

Comment: I't weird, have you cleaned and rebuild project?

Comment: i did every step, restarted eclipse and restared pc then error went away.